# Gibt es eine negative „doch“-Antwortpartikel?

Tags: single-word-request

„Ja“ ist die positive Antwort auf eine positive Frage.

> Hast du einen Hund? Ja.

„Doch“ ist die positive Antwort auf eine negative Frage.

> Hast du keinen Hund? Doch!

Was ist die negative Antwort auf positive/negative Fragen? Antwortet man „Nein“ auf beides, oder gibt es ein Wort, das das Gegenteil von „doch“ ist?

> Hast du einen Hund? **__**.
>
> Hast du keinen Hund? **__**.

Gibt es, geschichtlich, solch eine Antwortpartikel?

Answer (score 8):

In beiden Fällen benutzt man *nein*:

> Hast du einen Hund? Nein.
>   Hast du keinen Hund? Nein.

Siehe dazu auch [canoonet](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Satzart/Frage/Entscheidung.html;jsessionid=400E598C29486EFC8554D5DB93370172#Anchor-Antwort-14210).

Mir ist nicht bekannt, dass es früher eine negierte Antwortpartikel zu *doch* gab.

Comment: Manchmal verwendet man beim zweiten Beispiel als Zusatz noch die Wiederholung der Fragestellung, damit ganz klar ist, was gemeint ist: *Hast du keinen Hund?"* - *"Nein, habe ich nicht."*

Comment: Wow, ich hätte nie gedacht, dass grammatische Partikel _weiblich_ sind. (Die physikalischen sind zum Glück immer noch sächlich, und an die denke ich sehr viel öfter.)

Comment: @Hendrik: Das Wow gebührt Tim. Ich wollte seine Frage schon dahingehend korrigieren, habe mich aber dann doch noch mal versichert. Ich war auch überrascht. :)

Comment: Ah, jetzt sehe ich's - danke für den Hinweis!

Comment: Ich hab das Gefühl, auch schonmal Konstrukte à la "Hast du keinen Hund?" - "Ja, ich hab keinen Hund" gehört zu haben. Halte sie aber nicht für empfehlenswert. +1 auch für den Link! :)

Answer (score 6):

> Hast du einen Hund? `Ja.`
>   Du hast doch keinen Hund, oder? `Doch. / Oh ja. / Hab ich doch.`

Und jetzt mit nein:

> Hast du einen Hund? `Nein.`
>   Du hast doch keinen Hund, oder? `Nein. (diese Variante ist mißverständlich) / Oh nein. / Sicher nicht. / Nein, hab ich nicht. / Keineswegs.`

Comment: Imho klingt alles außer "Nein, hab ich nicht." ein wenig gestelzt.

Comment: Why not: "doch nicht"?

Comment: @Toby: Allenfalls: "Nicht doch! (Wie könnte ich einen Hund haben?)"

Answer (score 0):

Positive questions plus negative response is no deal

> Hast du einen Hund? Nein.

Negative questions plus negative response always require a bit more of clarification

> Hast du keinen Hund? Nein.

Logically this it would mean `I do not have no dog`, thus `I have one`. Nevertheless, without further clarification this is understood in the same way like above (`I do not have one`).

This is why one always puts smth like `Nein, hab ich nicht.` even though in the strict sense it's illogical (as it refers to a positive question).