# Was ist die richtige Antwort auf eine geschlossene Frage mit Verneinung?

Tags: negation, question

Welche Antwort soll ich geben, wenn ich auf eine geschlossene Frage mit Verneinung eine Antwort geben will, die zum Ausdruck bringen soll, dass das, was in der Frage verneint wird, zutrifft?

Beispiel:

Ich gehe zum Bäcker, kaufe zwei Semmeln um 70 Cent, und glaube nur einen 100-Euro-Schein in meiner Geldtasche zu haben. Als ich ihn dem Verkäufer gebe, fragt er:

> Haben Sie es nicht kleiner?

Ihm zuliebe sehe ich genauer nach und entdecke eine Ein-Euro-Münze. Während ich meine Handschuhe ausziehe, um die Münze herauszuholen, möchte ich seine geschlossene Frage mit einem simplen *ja* oder *nein* beantworten.

Was genau soll ich sagen?

### Nein

> Haben Sie es nicht kleiner?
>   Nein.

Die meisten Leute, die in dieser Situation **kein** Kleingeld haben, würden mit »*nein*« antworten. Von den meisten, die solche Fragen mit eingebauter Verneinung stellen, würde ein *nein* auch tatsächlich als Bestätigung ihrer Vermutung (*der hat sicher nur den Hunderter*), also als Zustimmung verstanden werden.

»*Nein*« wird also verstanden als: Ich habe es nicht kleiner und muss leider mit dem Hunderter zahlen.

Folglich sollte das Gegenteil (*ja*) auch das Gegenteil (*ich habe es kleiner*) bedeuten.

**Ja**

> Haben Sie es nicht kleiner?
>   Ja.

Wenn man das tatsächlich sagt, kann man sehr gut beobachten, wie sich das Gesicht des Verkäufers zur Mimik »Ratlosigkeit und Verblüffung« verformt, vor allem, wenn man sich mit dem Aushändigen der Euro-Münze ein paar Sekunden Zeit lässt.

Warum ist das so?

Wenn ich die Antwort zu einem ganzen Satz erweiterte, wird klar, dass es eigentlich die falsche Antwort ist:

> Haben Sie es nicht kleiner? – Ja.
>   Haben Sie es nicht kleiner? – Ja, ich habe es nicht kleiner.

Ich sage mit »*ja*« also aus, dass ich kein Kleingeld habe, und nicht anders als mit dem Hunderter zahlen kann.

Andererseits:
Ein *nein* würde für gewöhnlich als Abwesenheit von Kleingeld interpretiert werden (siehe oben), folglich wird das »ja« als dessen Gegenteil verstanden. Ich sage mit »ja« also aus, dass ich sehr wohl Kleingeld habe, und nicht unbedingt mit dem großen Hunderter zahlen muss.

Dass sich im Hirn des Verkäufers nun beide einander widersprechenden Interpretationen zugleich bilden, ist der Grund für das Entgleisen seiner Gesichtszüge.

### Noch einmal meine Frage

Welche Antwort soll ich geben, wenn ich auf eine geschlossene Frage mit Verneinung eine Antwort geben will, die zum Ausdruck bringen soll, dass das, was in der Frage verneint wird, zutrifft?

Comment: "Doch". Wurde eigentlich schon in Zusammenhang mit z.B. [dieser Frage](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/gibt-es-eine-negative-doch-antwortpartikel) beantwortet.

Comment: Das is so 'ne Sache mit *richtig* – vll. trifft es *grammatikalisch korrekt/richtig* eher.

Comment: Im Deutschen haben wir das Glück, dass es ein drittes Wort gibt. Im Englischen hat die Frage durchaus seine Berechtigung, da "Yes" zweideutig ist. Die im Bezug eigentlich interessante Frage ist (und du erwähnst sie irgendwo sogar): Warum bedeuten Ja und Nein hier das gleiche? Warum konkret heißt sogar der ganze Satz "Ja ich habe es nicht kleiner" und "Nein, ich habe es nicht kleiner" das gleiche? Obwohl du diese Frage erwähnst, scheint dein Kernpunkt zu sein, nach "doch" zu fragen. Mal abgesehen davon, dass ich nicht weiß, warum du die Frage stellst (du kennst das Wort doch), ist es ein Dupe.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Die richtige Antwort ist

> Doch.

Das ist das dritte Wörtchen im Ja-Nein-Doch-Gespann.

**Ja** bestätigt eine Aussage.

**Nein** verneint eine Aussage oder bestätigt eine negierte Aussage.

**Doch** verneint eine negierte Aussage.

Comment: Fast richtig, auch Ja kann eine negierte Aussage bestätigen: "Ist das nicht schön…?" - "Ja, das ist nicht schön."

Comment: @Barth Zalewski Das Beispiel ist Sarkasmus, das würde ich nicht für die Funktion der Sprache selbst zählen und zumindest ich würde "ja" auch nicht für etwas anderes als Sarkasmus verwenden. Was aber definitiv noch denkbar wäre, ist "genau". `Sie möchten nicht mit einer der oberen Worte antworten?" "Genau, es gibt nämlich noch Andere."`