# Negation in Frage: mit „Ja“ oder „Nein” antworten?

Tags: word-usage, question, negation

Wenn in einer Frage bereits eine Verneinung enthalten ist:

> Gehst du heute Abend **nicht** zum Konzert?

und man die Aussage der Frage verneinen möchte: Antwortet man dann – wie im Englischen (*No, I do not*) – mit einem *Nein* (so als hätte die Frage selbst keine Verneinung) oder mit einem *Ja* (Was das *Nein* in der Frage bestätigt)?

> **Nein**, ich gehe nicht hin. (Verneint, dass man zum Konzert geht)
>   **Ja**, ich gehe nicht hin. (Bejaht, dass man *nicht* zum Konzert geht)

Comment: Eine ähnliche Frage wurde hier bereits ähnlich gestellt: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20822/was-ist-die-richtige-antwort-auf-eine-geschlossene-frage-mit-verneinung. Sie zielt allerdings eher auf ein „Doch“ als Antwort ab.

Comment: Die typischen Antworten wären "Nee" und "Doch".

Comment: Man kann ja immer, wenn man sich über die Antwort nicht sicher ist nachfragen. Aber dann in der Nachfrage nicht wieder verneinen: "Gehst du heute abend nicht zum Konzert?" - "Nein" - "Also gehst du nicht?" ... ;-)

Answer (score 4):

> Gehst du heute Abend nicht zum Konzert?

Antwort »Ja« ist eindeutig (man geht nicht zum Konzert), Antwort »Nein« ist zweideutig, kann bedeuten:

> **a)** Ich gehe nicht zum Konzert. *(ist die Regel)*
>
> **b)** Was du mir in den Mund legst, trifft nicht zu, denn ich gehe sehr wohl zum Konzert. *(ist selten)*

Eindeutige Antworten derer, die zum Konzert gehen, wären z. B.

> - Doch
> - Natürlich / Selbstverständlich gehe ich hin

Eindeutige Antworten derer, die nicht zum Konzert gehen, wären z. B.

> - Ja
> - Stimmt / Korrekt / Richtig
> - Mit dem Kopf nicken

Comment: Ergänzend ist bei genau diesem Satzbau denkbar, dass "nicht" nicht als Negation, sondern als Partikel gebraucht wird. Dann wäre "Ja" bestätigend: Ein Konzertbesuch findet statt.

Comment: @npst: Stimmt, das ist denkbar, du meinst die Bedeutung _»War es nicht so, dass du heute Abend zum Konzert gehst?«_

Comment: Das ist ähnlich zweideutig, aber so mein ich's. "Nicht", wie man lokal auch "gell" oder "wa" sagen würde

Comment: @npst: Wenn du die Bedeutung _»Du gehst heute Abend zum Konzert, nicht wahr?«_ meinst, wüsste ich nicht, wie man die aus dem Originalsatz herauslesen könnte.

Comment: Du hast recht, ich dreh mich im Kreis. Ich ging von der Bedeutung aus, nicht vom Inhalt

Answer (score 2):

Von der Logik her müsste man in obigem Beispiel mit "ja" antworten, umgangssprachlich und instinktiv antworten die meisten jedoch mit "nein". Beides dürfte vom Gegenüber in der beabsichtigten Weise verstanden werden (oder der Gesprächspartner hakt nochmal nach), da die Alternative (also entgegen der Annahme des Fragers hinzugehen) fast schon zwingend ein "doch" (welches ein widersprechendes "ja" ist) erfordert.

Edit:

Wegen dieser Möglichkeit, die verneinte Frage mit "nein" zu bejahen, gab es ja bei Robert Lemkes "Was bin ich?" immer diese Fragekonstruktionen: "Gehe ich Recht in der Annahme, dass Sie nicht..."

Answer (score 1):

Wenn die Frage so formuliert ist, wird das *nicht* meiner Erfahrung nach in der Regel eher unbetont gesprochen und als Partikel verwendet.
Der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nicht_doch) beschreibt in diesem Fall die Bedeutung folgendermaßen:

> dient zur Bekräftigung und Bestätigung in Fragesätzen, die eine positive Antwort herausfordern, in Ausrufen o. Ä., die Zustimmung wünschen

Der Fragesteller geht also eher davon aus, dass als Antwort "Ja, ich gehe zum Konzert" folgt.

Für den Fall, dass wirklich das *nicht* (im Sinne einer Verneinung) in der Frage extra betont wird, wäre "Ja" eigentlich die richtige Antwort. Mit der Ergänzung "ich gehe nicht hin", würde aber im Prinzip jeder verstehen, dass du eben kein Konzert besuchen wirst unabhängig ob ein ja oder nein davor erwähnt wird.